# Alignments of widgets

Tags: android-layout, android-widget

I have one textview with four edittext in linearlayout oriented horizontally.On next linearlayout again I have one textview & four edit text.How to align them correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using http://www.droiddraw.org/ ?